# Function that halves the angle of a complex point

Tags: functions

How would a function mapping a complex point $z=re^{i\theta}$ to $re^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$ be correctly written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

note that $|z|=r$, so I think the answer you are looking for (and you can test it yourself) is 
$$f(z)=|z|\cdot \left( \frac{z}{|z|}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Ok, so there is no easy way to get the angle of the complex point? I have seen somewhere that $Arg~z$ might be used as a notation for that, is that correct?

Comment: This can be more succinctly written as $(|z|z)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, it's correct. To get the angle of $a+bi$ from the real axis, just draw a diagram and notice that $\frac{b}{a}$ is its tangent.

Comment: Yes I just wrote it out long way's so order of operations tells the story of what's happening.  Also yes, $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$

Comment: Is it possible to define a function as $f(a+bi)=\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$, or is that incorrect notation?

Comment: You might actually be after this: $e^{ix}=\cos(x) + i\sin (x)$ (not as your function, but as your starting point)

Comment: What is the domain of this function? I would be more careful using the notation $z^{1/2}$ because in order to define that, you need firstly to define a branch of $\log z $